# Php Does not print date in input

Tags: php, date, input, echo

PHP 5.3

Friends, I'm trying to insert the current date into an input, but it's not right, what do I do?

I tried everything and I can not find a solution, but in a normal echo it prints the input.
The only "error" that is that warning in the browser console.
The specified value "13-06-2019" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

In the beginning the page has:

```php
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); ?>
```

Prints:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mG1g.jpg

```php
<?php $actualDate = date('d-m-Y'); echo $actualDate.' | '.date('Y-m-d');?>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateRegister" id="dateRegister" value="<?php echo $actualDate; ?>" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateRegister" id="dateRegister" value="<?php echo $actualDate; ?>" readonly>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateRegister" id="dateRegister" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateRegister" id="dateRegister" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly>
```

> [Warning]

> The specified value "13-06-2019" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Look closely at `$actualDate = date('d-m-Y')`. What do you expect the date format string _"d-m-Y"_ to produce?

Comment: @Phil Even with Y-m-d does not work.

Comment: Prove it! Show what you've changed by [updating your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56589643/edit)

Comment: _Small Note_ `PHP5.3` has no friends. It reached end-of-life 5 years ago. Can you not upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Your code prints the value `13-06-2019` but requires a `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Instead of `$actualDate = date('d-m-Y')` you need to set `$actualDate = date('yyyy-MM-dd')`.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how PHP's `date()` function works ~ https://3v4l.org/6j2HH

Comment: Not work with date('yyyy-MM-dd'); He print 19191919-JunJun-1414

Comment: `date('Y-m-d')`